# Не отображается пункт меню

Tags: java, android, android-layout

В `ActionBar` не отображается пункт меню. Как его отобразить?

В файле разметки для меню прописал так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="test.prog1.MainActivity">
    <item android:title="@string/action_liked"
        android:id="@+id/action_liked"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

`action_liked` - нужно отобразить. Оно только в выпадающем меню появляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете не то пространство имен для атрибута `showAsAction` у первого пункта меню.

Замените `android:showAsAction="always"` на `app:showAsAction="always"`.

Comment: помогло, спасибо.

Comment: А как после нажатия на этот пункт из программы заменить иконку у этого пункта меню?

Comment: ок.. пока не могу только через 7 минут могу

Comment: @Сергей, StackOverflow – это не форум, это QA: один вопрос – один ответ. Если у Вас появился новый вопрос – создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: 40 минут ждать нужно для этого(

Comment: @Сергей, Посмотрите [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006749/change-icons-in-actionbar-dynamically).

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.